# How to get the gcp pubsub message in a cloudbuild yaml from a topic?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, terraform, nestjs

I have two repositories build on Nest JS.
On the execution of first repository on GCP when we create a PR one cloud build trigger gets executed and gets deployed.
Also on yaml of this 1st repo, I am publishing a topic with a message that will trigger an another cloud build which will deploy that 2nd repo image on gcp.

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish ${_PUBSUB_TOPIC} --message ${_PUBSUB_MESSAGE} --project ${_PROJECT_ID}
```

Now I am stuck, where I want to read the topic message and as per the message value I want take further steps forward in the yaml of the  2nd repo.

Comment: Do you want to trigger a 2nd pipeline on PubSub message?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I want to do that only, but I want the value of the pubsub message from the 1st pipeline, and upon checking that value I want to make decision of whether I trigger the 2nd pipeline or not.

Comment: Does this page resolve your issue? If not, what is missing? https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-pubsub-triggers#gcloud

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere What I want achieve is like, when my first trigger build is going on, it publishes a new topic with message, for eg, if the build is successful it will publish SUCCESS message or else with FAILED message.
When this build is finished, an another repo subscribes to this topic, and new cloud build trigger fires, and here I will get access and check to the message from before, and according to its success/fail msg, I will either execute the trigger build or not.

Comment: Yes, so Cloud Build trigger.